# Should I use Sequence internally and then convert to List

Tags: scala

Should my API's expose a List/Vector for collections but internally if I am using generic methods that are found on most collection types should I just use Seq for my collections?

Comment: Anything else you would expect in the answer for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using generic methods that are found on most collection types

For these methods I would actually advise to use `scala.collection.GenSeq`. 
What if you would like to reuse your methods for let's say parallel processing of your sequence? In that case `scala.collection.Seq` is not enough as `scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq` cannot be passed to the same method. For example:

```
def sumAll(seq: Seq[Int]): Int = seq.sum
```

Now you want to give a client an ability to use this method for parallel computing and you can either **introduce new "generic" method** like:

```
def sumAllPar(seq: Seq[Int]): Int = seq.par.sum
```

**or make your method truly generic by design**:

```
def sumAll(seq: GenSeq[Int]): Int = seq.sum
```

In this case the following invocations are valid:

```
sumAll(Seq(1,2,3))
sumAll(Seq(1,2,3).par)
```

> Should my API's expose a List/Vector for collections

**The same statement holds with one thing in mind**: restrict usages with more specific type (i.e: `Seq` - you do not want method to be invoked in parallel, `Array` - index access is needed and crucial etc).

Comment: Wasn't aware of GenSeq. Nifty.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly: you should use the simplest type that does everything you need - so your API and internal code should use Seq over List/Vector whenever possible. This means you do not make assumptions about implementation if you do not have to